# Network a-frame with nav-mesh or collision is not working. Either of one is working and not both

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, multiplayer

I'm using camera attached to head template also added this camera inside a rig and that rig is constrained to nav-mesh but only one is working either movement control of rig or wasd control of camera and not both.

```
<a-entity id="player-rig" movement-controls="constrainToNavMesh" >
    <a-entity
      id="player"
      networked="template:#avatar-template;attachTemplateToLocal:false;"
      camera="active:true;"
      wasd-controls="acceleration:12;"
      position="0 3.5 0"
      look-controls>
     </a-entity>
 </a-entity>
```

If there is any good way to use these both and if it works .Let me know

Comment: Try https://github.com/AdaRoseCannon/aframe-xr-boilerplate for the reference of nav-mesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a-entity
        id="cameraRig"
        movement-controls="speed:0.45;camera:#head;"
        simple-navmesh-constraint="navmesh:.navmesh;fall:0.5;height:0;exclude:.navmesh-hole;"        
        progressive-controls
        rotation="0 180 0"
        position="0 0 -14"
      >
        <!-- camera -->
        <a-entity
          id="head"
          camera="fov:85"
          look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: false"
          position="-0.179 1.15 0.106"
          spectator="true"
        >
          <a-gltf-model
            position="-0.04303 -1.54967 0.20197"
            rotation="0 180 0"
            src="#avatar"
            material="shader:standard"
          >
          </a-gltf-model>
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>
```

the above code worked for me, main part is the id of the camera("head" in this example). You need to put that in the movement-conrtols of camera rig.
I believe you have done adding nav-mesh gltf files and all.